# Ansible failing to ping Windows host from MACOS(source machine)

Tags: python, linux, macos, ansible, winrm

```
ansible all -m win_ping xx.xxx.xx.xx | FAILED! => { "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named winrm" }
```

Below are my settings

Source Machine MacOS: Pywinrm is installed successfully

```
pip list installed | grep winrm DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pywinrm 0.4.1
```

On windows: Winrm is enabled on target machine windows

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop> winrm qc WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Ansible version on my machine

```
ansible --version ansible 2.9.0 config file = /Users/xxxxx/.ansible.cfg configured module search path = [u'/Users/xxxxxx/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'] ansible python module location = /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible python version = 2.7.16 (default, Dec 3 2019, 07:02:07)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet ansible is running on python3 while you installed pywinrm on python 2.7. The output of `ansible --version` would help to diagnose. If I'm right => `pip3 install pywinrm`

Comment: Ok my bet was wrong. Meanwhile, please add that info directly to your question by clicking the edit button so that others trying to help you can find it quickly.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I can reach the Windows host from a Linux machine on the network, but not from my mac worksstation.

Answer (score 0):

by default ansible does not install pywinrm. You will need to manually install that module.

```
pip install "pywinrm>=0.3.0"
```

more details here - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#what-is-winrm

Comment: I have installed and still same error

| FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named winrm"
}